# How to create element from HTML in Prototype?

Tags: prototypejs, handlebars.js

Is there a way to create element from HTML in Prototype that's an analog to jQuery's `$('<div>Foo</div>')`?

Basically I create HTML chunk from a Handlebars template and want to insert into DOM but don't want to wrap it in some other element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this function as a 'static method' to Mustache for one of my recent projects to solve the same problem. I don't believe there is anything built-in to Prototype to solve this. I used hidden textareas to hold my template code, hence the `$F()` call. The last 3 lines are more specific to your problem - create a new div, insert your applied template html, then return the first descendant (as an element, by this point). This assumes your template only ever has one root element.

```
Mustache.createElementFromTemplateId = function(templateId, data) {
    if (!this.cachedTemplates) this.cachedTemplates = {};

    var templateStr = this.cachedTemplates[templateId];
    if (!templateStr) {
        templateStr = $F(templateId);
        this.cachedTemplates[templateId] = templateStr;
    }

    var appliedTemplateStr = this.render(templateStr, data);

    var div = new Element("div");
    div.insert( appliedTemplateStr );
    return div.firstDescendant();
};
```

Comment: Thanks. This one `firstDescendant()` is what I was looking for. Honestly, can't stand Prototype. Used jQuery for a few years and now have to switch to Prototype for my job and I don't get this library. Like it was written by children.

Comment: Whaaa?! Prototype is the bomb! I find it super intuitive and fun to use. I feel like a n00b with jQuery. I suppose it comes down to which framework you're first exposed to.

Comment: Not sure. In jQuery you can just declare a new element by $('whatever HTML code'). Especially useful when you use microtemplates and DON'T want to wrap them into extra elements. Or, all kind of event bindings (bind, live, delegate, 'click' etc) are super useful, and Prototypes seem to only have 'observe'.

Comment: Check out [Event.on](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/on/) - It's basically all the jQuery event handling methods you mentioned above in one method. It seems to be the same as jQuery's [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) from what I can tell. I'd advise to never use `Event.observe` and always use `Event.on`. I'm not trying to argue or anything, just trying to point out a hugely useful part of Prototype.