# Manually Rendering a Prototype JS Element Object

Tags: javascript, html, dom, prototypejs

Is it possible to manually render a Prototype JS element without using one of the `update`, `insert`, etc methods?  If so, how?

That is, if I have the code

```
var test = new Element('div');
test.update("This is a test");
```

Is there a way to get a javascript variable with the string

```
<div>Hello</code>
```

Comment: Are you inquiring if it is possible to simulate a jQuery selector using strings inputted as HTML elements in order to create an element as that string? Do you know what jQuery is -- http://jquery.com/?

Comment: @David: No, I'm asking if it's possible to serialize a Prototype JS Element object as a string.  I'm aware what jQuery is, and my question isn't about jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unclear on your question. If you're asking to make a string representation of an element (created with Prototype or not), you're looking for [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.outerHTML).

```
var test = new Element('div');
test.update("This is a test");

var htmlString = test.outerHTML;
alert(htmlString);  // "<div>This is a test</div>"
```

​
If you're asking if it's possible to create an element from the string `<div>This is a test</div>` using Prototype, the answer is no. Well, there's nothing built in that does this. You can easily create your own function to handle this, though. Here's a similar Q/A on the topic: [How to create element from HTML in Prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551647/how-to-create-element-from-html-in-prototype/11564472#11564472)